# Problems with $this->getRoute()->getObject() losing it's context.

Tags: symfony1

Please see my question in the template section below:

Form (showSuccess):

```
<?php echo form_tag('job/salarySubmit') ?>
<input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php echo $job->getId(); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="View Salary">
</form>
```

Action:

```
public function executeSalarySubmit(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod('post'));
    $param = array('job_id' => $request->getParameter('job_id'), ); 
    $this->redirect('job/salary?'.http_build_query($param)); 
}

public function executeSalary(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->object_id = $request->getParameter('job_id');
    $this->salary = $this->getRoute()->getObject();          
}
```

Template (salarySuccess.php):

```
<?php echo $object_id; ?>  // returns correct job_id: 6100, but when I try to access the object's other getters (example: echo $object_id->getName(), I get "Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object"
<?php echo $salary->getName(); ?> //works, but it gets the wrong name. It's returning the  first job in my DB with an ID of "1" which is not correct... it needs to be 6100
```

Routing:

```
job_salary:
  url:      /job/salary/:job_id
  param:    { module: job, action: salary }
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Job, type: object }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    sf_method: [GET]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `var_dump()` on your template variables.
You'll see that `$object_id` is not an object (it is a non-object, like the error message says). `$object_id` is most likely a string or an integer and its value must be "6100".
`$salary` is not the object you're looking for, because sfDoctrineRoute looks for a parameter called `id`, and you named it job_id in your routing.yml (which is strange, because you name it `id` in this route's requirements.

Comment: silly me.  I overlooked the naming conflict.  I changed everything to "id" and it worked perfectly.  Thanks for the extra set of eyes.